# I made this lengthy code for a small thing is there any alternative of this code to make it shorter

Tags: jquery

I made this lengthy code for a small thing is there any alternative of this code to make it shorter and the limit of the input change according to the selected option. The basic problem is i have to change the limit of the input according to the selected option for that i have to make 8 different input for each separate option that become too lengthy, I want to make the code shorter and only one input is enough that limit change according to the selected option and also it show a small message of limit on the top of input so that user know how much values user has to enter

```
 <tr> 
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <label for = "symbolsize"><b> PCB's symbol size Rows x Columns *</b></label><br><br>
                            <select id="symbolsize" name="symbolsize" style="width: 350px; height: 35px; border-radius: 8px" required />
                                <option value="" disabled selected> Please Select... </option>
                                <option value="1"> 10 x 10 </option>
                                <option value="2"> 12 x 12</option> 
                                <option value="3"> 14 x 14 </option>
                                <option value="4"> 16 x 16</option> 
                                <option value="5"> 18 x 18 </option>
                                <option value="6"> 20 x 20</option> 
                                <option value="7"> 22 x 22 </option>
                                <option value="8"> 24 x 24 </option>   
                            </select><br><br>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize1">
                            <label for = "codesize1"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.27mm and 3.81mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="1.27" max="3.81" name = "codesize1" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize2">
                            <label for = "codesize2"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.52mm and 4.57mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="1.52" max="4.57" name = "codesize2" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize3">
                            <label for = "codesize3"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.78mm and 5.33mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="1.78" max="5.33" name = "codesize3" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize4">
                            <label for = "codesize4"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.03mm and 6.1mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="2.03" max="6.1" name = "codesize4" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>  
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize5">
                            <label for = "codesize5"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.29mm and 6.87mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="2.29" max="6.87" name = "codesize5" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize6">
                            <label for = "codesize6"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.54mm and 7.62mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="2.54" max="7.62" name = "codesize6" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize7">
                            <label for = "codesize7"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.79mm and 8.38mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="2.79" max="8.38" name = "codesize7" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id = "codesize8">
                            <label for = "codesize8"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 3.05mm and 9.14mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
                            <input type = "number" step="any" min="3.05" max="9.14" name = "codesize8" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#symbolsize").change(function() {
                                sizeofcode();
                            });
                        });
                        function sizeofcode() {
                            if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 1){
                               $("#codesize1").show(); 
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize1").hide();
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 2){
                              $("#codesize2").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize2").hide(); 
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 3){
                              $("#codesize3").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize3").hide(); 
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 4){
                              $("#codesize4").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize4").hide(); 
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 5){
                               $("#codesize5").show(); 
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize5").hide();
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 6){
                              $("#codesize6").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize6").hide(); 
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 7){
                              $("#codesize7").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize7").hide(); 
                            }if ($("#symbolsize").val() == 8){
                              $("#codesize8").show();
                            }else{
                              $("#codesize8").hide(); 
                            }      
                        }
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can short it down to something like this:

```
function sizeofcode() {
  $("[id^=codesize]").hide()
  $("#codesize" + $("#symbolsize").val()).show();
}
```

`$("[id^=codesize]").hide()` will hide all elements that has an `id` starting with `codesize`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#symbolsize").change(function() {
    sizeofcode();
  });
});

function sizeofcode() {
  $("[id^=codesize]").hide()
  $("#codesize" + $("#symbolsize").val()).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%">
      <label for="symbolsize"><b> PCB's symbol size Rows x Columns *</b></label><br><br>
      <select id="symbolsize" name="symbolsize" style="width: 350px; height: 35px; border-radius: 8px" required />
      <option value="" disabled selected> Please Select... </option>
      <option value="1"> 10 x 10 </option>
      <option value="2"> 12 x 12</option>
      <option value="3"> 14 x 14 </option>
      <option value="4"> 16 x 16</option>
      <option value="5"> 18 x 18 </option>
      <option value="6"> 20 x 20</option>
      <option value="7"> 22 x 22 </option>
      <option value="8"> 24 x 24 </option>
      </select><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize1">
      <label for="codesize1"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.27mm and 3.81mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="1.27" max="3.81" name="codesize1" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize2">
      <label for="codesize2"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.52mm and 4.57mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="1.52" max="4.57" name="codesize2" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize3">
      <label for="codesize3"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 1.78mm and 5.33mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="1.78" max="5.33" name="codesize3" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize4">
      <label for="codesize4"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.03mm and 6.1mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="2.03" max="6.1" name="codesize4" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize5">
      <label for="codesize5"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.29mm and 6.87mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="2.29" max="6.87" name="codesize5" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize6">
      <label for="codesize6"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.54mm and 7.62mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="2.54" max="7.62" name="codesize6" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize7">
      <label for="codesize7"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 2.79mm and 8.38mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="2.79" max="8.38" name="codesize7" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; display: none" id="codesize8">
      <label for="codesize8"><b><span style="color:red">Please enter the size of the code between 3.05mm and 9.14mm *</span> </b></label><br><br>
      <input type="number" step="any" min="3.05" max="9.14" name="codesize8" style="width: 350px; height: 25px; border-radius: 8px" required /><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you please explain me about this $("[id^=codesize]").hide()  how does it work, Many thanks for helping me

Comment: `$("[id^=codesize]")` means that it will select all element where the `id` of the element starts with `codesize`

Comment: This function is working perfectly but, I am using required attribute in each input fields, when i click submit button then i get this error in the console " An invalid form control with name='codesize1' is not focusable" " An invalid form control with name='codesize2' is not focusable." " An invalid form control with name='codesize4' is not focusable. " and son on.

Comment: To fix this problem i have to keep the value of hidden input fields 0, I have been trying to do with this code but couldn't do it, with my previous old lengthy code i can do but this small code i couldn't do it could ou please help out me, i want to use this small code

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can update `sizeofcode` function like this:

```
function sizeofcode() {
    $('[id^=codesize]').hide();
    $(`#codesize${$("#symbolsize").val()}`).show(); 
}
```

- This will first hide all elements where `id` starts with `codesize`

  - More info: [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- and only show the particular element based on `#symbolsize` selected value.

Comment: Sure. Please create a separate question for your requirement and mention all the details. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but i haven't tested it.

```
function sizeofcode() {
    symbolsizeVal = $("#symbolsize").val();
    $("[id^=codesize]").hide(); 
    $("#codesize" + symbolsizeVal).show();
}
```

Comment: when i submit form then i get error in the console, because i am using required field in each input fields. To avoid such problem i have to keep the value of each hidden input field 0, do you know how can i do that?